# parse custom facebook/google login. revocable sessions

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, oauth, google-plus

I've hit the following walls with parse.

1) You can't put your own json into the authData field in the users table. 
2) I've implemented my own facebook token validation and google + token validation.I know parse has built in parse facebook but I wanted to be as free as I can on the client part. I use the facebook and google sdk on android, get a token -> submit to parse cloud code. Verifiy the integrity and validity of the token for each platform (facebook/google+)

Problems :

1) Because you can't fill the authData field with your own json, you need to create another field with facebook/google authorization data but this problem leads to 2nd problem
2) If your facebook account and google account are based on the same email, you can't create 2 users with the same email because of parse users table require for the email to be unique. There would be 2 different accounts with the same email but different authorizaton data. Now I am forced to rewrite the authorziation data if the same email logins with facebook then google etc, instead of having different accounts.

3) You get a session token with revocable session on only when using signup or login. Let's take the following scenario :

a) I have a entry in the user table with a user that has logged in with facebook. At his first login, an account is made. Email + custom column authorization data because I can't write my own json into the "authData" column. Of course after sign up, the parse cloud code gives me a session token which I use on the client to login a parse user. (parse.user.become etc)

b) User uninstalls the app or logs out. User comes back to the app. I verify the integrity of the new token given by facebook sdk on android. Check for existence of user in cloud code. User exists, but getSessionsToken() is null when revocable session is on, so I don't have a sessionToken to return to my app to login any users in the app itself.

c) The only time when revocable sessions are on when parse gives you a session token is when you use signup and login. For a returning user, using login doesn't work because login requires the username and password and you would have to put the same password for all users that login with a provider (facebook/google+/linkedin etc)

When you query for a user and revocable sessions are off, you get a session token, so you can login the user.

Comment: +1 exactly what my issues with parse are. There is a decent article: https://parse.com/tutorials/adding-third-party-authentication-to-your-web-app. I have revocable sessions off for the same reasons too.